# Fixing scraping from html to csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, export-to-csv

I've been working on a Python script that scrapes election data from a website and writes it to a CSV file. The script utilizes requests to fetch page content and BeautifulSoup for parsing HTML. It should extract specific data points: registered voters, issued envelopes, and valid votes, then write this data into a CSV file with appropriate headers.

Despite following the logic and ensuring the CSV file is opened correctly for writing, the output file is unexpectedly empty, and I'm unable to pinpoint the exact issue within the script. I have verified that the URLs being processed are correct, and the script does not raise any exceptions during execution.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could review my code and provide insights into what might be causing the script to fail at writing data to the CSV. Below is the core function of the script, where I think might be the issue:

```
def main(base_url, query_string):
    processed_urls = set()
    main_url = base_url + query_string
    main_page_content = fetch_page_content(main_url)

    csv_file = "my_actual_path"

    # Open the CSV file for writing
    with open(csv_file, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8-sig') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
        
        # Write the header based on your screenshot
        writer.writerow(['registered', 'envelopes', 'valid'])

        # Check if content was fetched successfully
        if main_page_content:
            all_links = parse_links(main_page_content)
            
            # Process each link found
            for a_tag in all_links:
                href = a_tag.get('href')
                if href and not href.startswith('http'):
                    # Concatenate base URL with href only if it's a relative path
                    full_url = f"{base_url.rstrip('/')}/{href.lstrip('/')}"
                    
                    # Check if the URL has already been processed
                    if full_url not in processed_urls:
                        processed_urls.add(full_url)
                        result = extract_table_data(full_url, processed_urls, base_url)

                        # Write the extracted data to the CSV file
                        for record in result:
                            try:
                                writer.writerow([record['volici_v_seznamu'], record['vydane_obalky'], record['platne_hlasy']])
                            except KeyError as e:
                                # This will print an error message if the expected keys are not in the record
                                print(f"Missing data for key {e} in record: {record}")
    
    print(f"Data has been written to {csv_file}")
```

The script should extract information about voters, issued envelopes, and valid votes from a table on a webpage and then output this data into a CSV file with headers 'registered', 'envelopes', and 'valid'.
However, when I run my script, the resulting CSV file is empty, which suggests that either the data is not being extracted correctly from the website or there is an issue with writing the data to the file. I've checked my functions for fetching the page content and parsing the data, and they seem to be working individually, but when integrated into the main script, they are not producing the expected output.
I was expecting the script to output a CSV file filled with rows of data corresponding to each municipality, including the number of registered voters, the number of envelopes issued, and the number of valid votes, but instead, I'm left with an empty file or incorrectly formatted data. I'm looking for insights into where my code might be going wrong and why the expected output isn't being generated.

Comment: Is the header line being written to the CSV file?

Comment: Are you sure the data you want is in the HTML? Many websites generate results dynamically using JavaScript, you need to use Selenium WebDriver to get the dynamic results.

Comment: Yes, the header line is being written to the CSV and also the data is in the HTML, when I print it out as a dictionary it works, put putting it in the CSV doesn't

Comment: I somehow fixed it, but thank you anyways